# Forming an insert statement with single quotes in Python with Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-8.4

I am having a field called comments.
I am effectively trying to read values from one large table into multiple tables.
Hence, my select query fetches the comment field for me.

I am constructing a Python script to do the copying from table to table.
My insert query fails when it encounters a comment field like "Sorry! we can't process your order" because of the single quote.

I have tried using $ quotes but in vain

Here is what I am trying

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='localhost' )
mark=conn.cursor()
/* fectching the rows and doing other stuff */

addthis="insert into my_table(something) values("$$"+str(row[8])+"$$")
mark.execute(addthis)
conn.commit()
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: You need to find a new database tutorial, as your current one is failing you badly.

Comment: Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: I have no option! Do u have any other workarounds?

Comment: Yes. Use DB-API 2 as it's meant to be used. See a tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Your insert statement should use a placeholder. In the case of psycopg2, it is `%s`.
2. You should pass the parameter(s) as a second argument to `execute()`. That way you don't have quoting issues and you guard against SQL-injection attack.

For example:

```
addthis = "INSERT INTO my_table (something) VALUES (%s);"
mark.execute(addthis, ('a string you wish to insert',))
```

Answer (score -3):

You could use a placeholder, as suggested by *bernie*. **This is the preferred way.**
There are however situations where using a placeholder is not possible. You then have to escape the qoutes manually. This is done by backslashing them:

```
addthis="insert into my_table(something) values(%s)" % str(row[8]).replace('"', r'\"').replace("'", r"\'")
mark.execute(addthis)
```

Comment: No - he should use a placeholder. If you're asking questions like this, then the last thing you should do is start putting together your own ad-hoc escaping. Yours doesn't work anyway.